# Animation is not working on a matplotlib gridspec

Tags: python-3.x, animation, matplotlib, anaconda

I have reviewed the answer to the question:
[how to use GridSpec() with FuncAnimation in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44486263/how-to-use-gridspec-with-funcanimation-in-matplotlib?newreg=b7754677debe41609160d4a764d7b459)

however I believe I am doing something wrong but do not know what, my mission here is to create multiple animations for each of the grids and I also used a code mode for a gauge to animate the count of used data.

```
x1 = np.random.normal(-2.5, 1, 10000)
x2 = np.random.gamma(2, 1.5, 10000)
x3 = np.random.exponential(2, 10000)+7
x4 = np.random.uniform(14,20, 10000)
xrand = np.random.random(size = 10000)
x = [x1, x2, x3, x4]
plt.figure()

gspec = gridspec.GridSpec(3,3, wspace = 0.25)
GS1 = plt.subplot(gspec[0, 0])
GS2 = plt.subplot(gspec[0, 1])
GS3 = plt.subplot(gspec[1, 0])
GS4 = plt.subplot(gspec[1, 1])
GS5 = plt.subplot(gspec[0:,2:])
GS6 = plt.subplot(gspec[2,:2])
GS = [GS1, GS2, GS3, GS4,  GS5, GS6]


bins1 = np.arange(-7.5, 2.5, 0.2)
bins2 = np.arange(0, 10, 0.2)
bins3 = np.arange(7, 17, 0.2)
bins4 = np.arange(12, 22, 0.2)
bins = [bins1, bins2, bins3, bins4]

axis1 = [-7.5, 2.5, 0, 0.6]
axis2 = [0, 10, 0, 0.6]
axis3 = [7, 17, 0, 0.6]
axis4 = [12, 22, 0, 0.6]
axis  = [axis1, axis2, axis3, axis4]

GS1.hist(x1, bins = 1000)
GS2.hist(x2, bins = 1000)
GS3.hist(x3, bins = 1000)
GS4.hist(x4, bins = 1000)
GS5.scatter(x1, xrand, norm = True, c = 'r', s= 0.7)
GS5.scatter(x2, xrand, norm = True, c = 'g', s= 0.7)
GS5.scatter(x3, xrand, norm = True, c = 'b', s= 0.7)
GS5.scatter(x4, xrand, norm = True, c = 'y', s= 0.7)

for s in GS:
    s.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    s.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
gspec.update(wspace = .6, hspace = .6)

fig, ((GS1,GS2),(GS3, GS4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharey = True)
GS = [GS1, GS2, GS3, GS4]


def update(curr):
    if curr == 500:
        a.event_source.stop()
    for i in range(0, len(GS)):
        GS[i].hist(x[i][:curr], bins = bins[i], normed = True)
        GS[i].axis(axis[i])
        GS[i].gca().set_title('Sampling random distribution')
        GS[i].gca().set_ylabel('Frequency')
        GS[i].gca().set_xlabel('Value')
        GS[i].annotate('n = {}'.format(curr), [3,27])
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

fig = plt.gcf()    
a = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval = 10) #, blit = True, repeat = True)
```

I do not understand what is the problem with the code.

Comment: What *is* the problem? Do you get an error? Is the output not animating?

Comment: The animation is not working actually, best I got after tuning the code was the gridspec is drawn with the frames and everything, but no data is graphed or animated.

Comment: What's the purpose of this? Currently you are trying to plot a histogram with the data being the axes. Usually a histogram has numeric data as input, in this case probably `x1`, `x2` etc. but those do not appear in your updating function.

Comment: Ok this is basically a 4 part subplot where I intend to animate each histogram, the data is indeed x1, x2 etc. I updated the updating function as follows:
def update(curr):
    if curr == 500:
        a.event_source.stop()
    for i in range(0, len(GS)):
        GS[i].hist(x[i][:curr], bins = bins[i], normed = True)
        GS[i].axis(axis[i])
        GS[i].gca().set_title('Sampling random distribution')
        GS[i].gca().set_ylabel('Frequency')
        GS[i].gca().set_xlabel('Value')
        GS[i].annotate('n = {}'.format(curr), [3,27])
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

Comment: Can you please not show extensive code in the comments, but rather use your question for showing it?

Comment: Sorry this is my first time here! and in coding as well

Answer (score 0):

Problems:

- You cannot use `plt.show()` inside the updating function.
- `GS[i].gca().set_title` does not make sense, because `GS[i]` already *is* an axes, which does not have any `gca()` method. Same for `set_ylabel` and `set_xlabel`.
- You need to call `tight_layout()` only once outside the loop.
- You will need to remove the old histogram before plotting a new one on the axes.

Possibly the following is what you're after:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import animation

x1 = np.random.normal(-2.5, 1, 10000)
x2 = np.random.gamma(2, 1.5, 10000)
x3 = np.random.exponential(2, 10000)+7
x4 = np.random.uniform(14,20, 10000)
xrand = np.random.random(size = 10000)
x = [x1, x2, x3, x4]

bins1 = np.arange(-7.5, 2.5, 0.2)
bins2 = np.arange(0, 10, 0.2)
bins3 = np.arange(7, 17, 0.2)
bins4 = np.arange(12, 22, 0.2)
bins = [bins1, bins2, bins3, bins4]

axis1 = [-7.5, 2.5, 0, 0.6]
axis2 = [0, 10, 0, 0.6]
axis3 = [7, 17, 0, 0.6]
axis4 = [12, 22, 0, 0.6]
axis  = [axis1, axis2, axis3, axis4]


fig, ((GS1,GS2),(GS3, GS4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharey = True)
GS = [GS1, GS2, GS3, GS4]


def update(curr):
    if curr == 500:
        a.event_source.stop()
    for i in range(0, len(GS)):
        GS[i].clear()
        GS[i].hist(x[i][:curr], bins = bins[i], normed = True)
        GS[i].axis(axis[i])
        GS[i].set_title('Sampling random distribution')
        GS[i].set_ylabel('Frequency')
        GS[i].set_xlabel('Value')
        GS[i].annotate('n = {}'.format(curr), [3,27])


plt.tight_layout()
fig = plt.gcf()    
a = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval = 10)

plt.show()
```